# Tool to inspect and parse an inbox

Tags: email, parsing

I have a inbox that receives lots of emails from my various systems and such as Nagios and Azure alerts regarding disk usage, exceptions and job failures.

Since I get so many of these alerts, I was wondering if there was any tools that I could use to filter out and only receive the most important alerts - a lot of these are spam that are only affecting my development environments and so I only want to be alerted only when something goes wrong with my production environment.

Does anyone know of any such tools or knows a better way of dealing with this sort a problem? There must be a better solution to this rather than manually reading through all my emails and checking the contents.

I've heard of a tool known as LogRythm but I'm under the impression that this is purely a data security tool and am unsure whether it would be able to parse an inbox.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is [IMAPfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter). This is a utility for Linux systems (but I run it on Windows with the Linux Subsystem) that uses the IMAP protocol to manage one or more mailboxes.

You need to define all your filters and actions using the Lua language (but it's pretty simple, in the GitHub there are many examples) and keep the program running all the time (if the program is not running, all mails will arrive unfiltered, and they will be reorganized once the program is started again)

This is not a pretty software (no GUI, weird language, needs an always on server to have real time filtering), but since you can program your filters you can do pretty much anything, and it's also very light